# Using arrow keys in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, arrow-keys, nsevent

I was doing a little research into this, and I found
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275088/how-do-i-collect-key-input-in-a-video-game-style-cocoa-app)
 question. I implemented the code used there, but nothing happened. Here is the exact code I am using:

.h file

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface Test : NSView {

}

-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent*)event;
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "Test.h"


@implementation Test

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"A key has been pressed");
    switch( [event keyCode] ) {
        case 126:       // up arrow
        case 125:       // down arrow
        case 124:       // right arrow
        case 123:       // left arrow
            NSLog(@"Arrow key pressed!");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Key pressed: %@", event);
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

What is wrong? Is there something that I have to add to the interface?

EDIT: Well, something actually *did* happen. I my computer beeped at me. Nothing more.

Comment: Did you add the view to a NSWindow?

Comment: I believe I did, yes. I even set the class to Test, and made the view cover the entire window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle arrow key event in Cocoa app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000133/how-to-handle-arrow-key-event-in-cocoa-app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement `acceptsFirstResponder`:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Also, make sure that your view is first responder (e.g. by clicking inside the view).