# NSOpenGLView, NSWindow & NSResponder - makeFirstResponder not working

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, keydown, nsevent, first-responder

In the code below I am Initialising a `NSViewController` [a NSResponder], with a `NSWindow`, a `NSOpenGLView`, presenting the view and attempting to set the `NSViewController` as the windows first responder.

It is not working. I was expecting to be able to hit a breakpoint in the `keyUp:` and `keyDown:` methods also below, but nothing is happening.

Am I missing something?

```
-(void)initwithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    window = [[MyNSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame styleMask:NSClosableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered                           defer: YES ];   


    OpenGLView* glView = [[[OpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame] autorelease];

    window.contentView = glView;

    [window makeFirstResponder:self];   
    [window makeKeyWindow];     

    [window display];   
}   

-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent
{
    unichar unicodeKey = [ [ theEvent characters ] characterAtIndex:0 ];
    unicodeKey = 0;
}

-(void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    unichar unicodeKey = [ [ theEvent characters ] characterAtIndex:0 ];
    unicodeKey = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Returning to this issue, actually the problem is elsewhere.

I had been using this sleep function to control the apps frame rate:

```
void System::Sleep(double seconds)
{
    NSDate* limit       = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:seconds];
    NSRunLoop* runLoop  = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    [runLoop runUntilDate:limit];
}
```

Doing this seems to freeze the system completely and block the key events.

Instead use this to schedule the update function:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:self selector:@selector(updateApp:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

For instances to participate in key-view loops, a custom view must return **YES** from **acceptsFirstResponder**.

Comment: Since making this post I have tried adding the following to the view class:

-(BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
Did not affect the behaviour.

Comment: @BROK3NS0UL Try something like - (void)keyDown:(NSEvent*)theEvent { NSString *characters = [theEvent characters]; NSLog(@"Key: ", characters); }

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also.  This thread might help

[keyDown not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622255/keydown-not-being-called)

> I found out what was preventing the keyDown event from being called.
>   It was the NSBorderlessWindowMask mask, it prevents the window from
>   become the key and main window. So I have created a subclass of
>   NSWindow called BorderlessWindow:

```
 @interface BorderlessWindow : NSWindow { }

 @end

 @implementation BorderlessWindow

 - (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
     return YES; }

 - (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
     return YES; }

 @end
```