# keyDown not being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keyboard, nswindow, keydown

I have a custom NSView called SurfaceView. It is the contentView of a NSWindow and it handles basic events like mouse click and drawing. But don't matters what I do, it does not handle the keyDown function. I've already override the acceptsFirstResponder but nothing happens.

If it matters, I run the application using a custom NSEvent loop, shown below:

```
NSDictionary* info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* mainNibName = [info objectForKey:@"NSMainNibFile"];

NSApplication* app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
NSNib* mainNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:mainNibName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[mainNib instantiateNibWithOwner:app topLevelObjects:nil];

[app finishLaunching];

while(true)
{   
    NSEvent* event = [app nextEventMatchingMask:NSAnyEventMask untilDate:[NSDate date] inMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode dequeue:YES];
    [app sendEvent:event];

    // Some code is execute here every frame to do some tasks...

    usleep(5000);
}
```

Here's the SurfaceView code:

```
@interface SurfaceView : NSView
{
    Panel* panel;
}

@property (nonatomic) Panel* panel;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
- (BOOL)isFlipped;
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent;
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder;
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder;

@end
```

--

```
@implementation SurfaceView

@synthesize panel;

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
};

- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    // this function is never called
};

...

@end
```

Here's how I create the view:

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(left, top, wide, tall) styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];

...

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

SurfaceView* mainView = [SurfaceView alloc];
[mainView initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, wide, tall)];
mainView.panel = panel;
[window setContentView:mainView];
[window setInitialFirstResponder:mainView];
[window setNextResponder:mainView];
[window makeFirstResponder:mainView];
```

Comment: Have you overridden `-becomeFirstResponder` too? And after the makeFirstResponder call, can you `NSLog(@"%@", window.firstResponder)` to double check if the SurfaceView really is the First Responder?

Comment: Just a quick note, delete all of your method declaration in your interface file, as they're already declared in NSView already.  No need to declare them again.

Comment: And also, what's with the semicolons at the end of each method?

Comment: @Vervious Yes. And the `window.firstResponder` is the SurfaceView.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer It's a bad practice I earned from C++.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found out what was preventing the `keyDown` event from being called. It was the `NSBorderlessWindowMask` mask, it prevents the window from become the key and main window. So I have created a subclass of `NSWindow` called `BorderlessWindow`:

```
@interface BorderlessWindow : NSWindow
{
}

@end

@implementation BorderlessWindow

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Holly s*! You save my day!

Comment: Thanks so much for this. You saved me a lot of time. For those using swift with NSViewController you can simply make an extension of NSWindow and return true on these methods.

Comment: @Epic Byte - This is not correct. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) :  "You cannot use extensions to override existing methods or properties on Objective-C types"

Comment: @TeoSartori That comment was made when overriding was possible with extensions.

Comment: Then it is worth correcting. I wasted some time not getting it working before doubting the comment and checking the docs.

Comment: After two hours of search, this was the solution

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answer: Check in your IB checkbox for `NSWindow`.

`Title Bar` should be checked. It the similar to `NSBorderlessWindowMask`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to override the `keyDown` method on both **NSView** and **NSWindow** (created a customization of both). In the **NSWindow** in the `keyDown` override I had to call

```
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *) event {

    if (self.firstResponder != self) {
    
        [self.firstResponder keyDown:event];
    }
}
```

to let the event reach the view. Of course I had also to call `makeFirstResponder` first on the **NSWindow** and pass the `contentView` to it :

```
[window makeFirstResponder: [window contentView] ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11638926/2142577) saved me a ton of time

I tested out with Swift 5 + Xcode 15, here's how how you write it in Swift

```swift
class BorderlessWindow: NSWindow {
  override var canBecomeKey: Bool {
    return true
  }

  override var canBecomeMain: Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Also, I find that `canBecomeMain` is not necessary. `canBecomeKey` alone is enough to solve the problem.